# Automating routes with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm integrating CI into another script as a module, and I need to configure and setup routes to work normally but from inside this parent scripts mod rewrites and so on.

Basically to start the Parent Script routes all URL's with `m/MODULE_NAME` to a module folder.
Inside this module folder is where I have CI taking over and handling requests sent to it.

When I view all the segments of a request to: `http://www.example.com/folder/m/memberships`

CI prints the segments out like this:

```
array( [0] => 'folder', [1] => 'm', [2] => 'memberships' )
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the configuration settings so that Routing is done automatically after `/m/memberships`.

Right now I am basically setting each route up individually:

```
// Main config routes
$route['(:any)/m/memberships'] = 'home';
$route['(:any)/m/memberships/admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['(:any)/m/memberships/admin/config'] = 'admin/config';
```

I tried setting the base url to `http://www.domain.com/m/memberships`, but then even the routes listed here weren't being added to segments and I couldn't point them to the proper controllers.

Anyone have any suggestions?  I'm fairly new to CI.

EDIT:
These are some configs I have setup that might help:

```
$config['base_url']   = 'http://www.domain.com/folder/';
$config['index_page']    = '';
$config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: You don't need to set `/admin/config` if its controler/method. it will do that by default.

Comment: It's a pretty particular setup as I'm inside another script and leaving it empty doesn't work.  I guess I having more of a configuration issue than a routing one.

Comment: Can you give an indication as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey I added some more details to the question to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how to do that

1) is set `$config['base_url']   = 'http://www.domain.com/folder/m/memberships';`
and clear routes

2) set route `$route['m/memberships/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2';`

the first one is much cleaner